# Token ring assignment

Tags: sockets, network-programming, token

I have a college assignment coming up and I need to simulate token ring protocol. I'm allowed to use any programming language but I'm not sure which to pick. What's the best language to use for this type of assignment?  I have pretty limited experience with Java and C++ but I'd be willing to learn a different language if there's a better option. Just hoping to get an opinion from someone wiser who has experience in this area!

Comment: Both Java and C++ will do

Answer (score 1):

C++, Java and C are all good for implementing communication protocols. What language you choose should essentially depend on your requirements - the time requirements, optimizing calls to native code, etc. (C++ is generally considered faster than Java)

Personally, I'll prefer C++ and C, because most native code ( for OS, communication devices) is written in these two languages. Even your Java classes will, at some point or the other, communicate with native code written in C++/C.